# Where are isoboot, boot=isolinux and iso-scan/filename parameters documented?

Tags: grub2, dracut

I see this example in the dracut docs:

```
linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz0 
    boot=isolinux
    iso-scan/filename=$isofile
    root=live:LABEL=$isolabel
    ro
    rd.live.image
```

These texts:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
- https://github.com/haraldh/dracut/blob/master/dracut.cmdline.7.asc

don't explain these parameters in detail.

casper hook is from another system 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/casper.7.html
(not related, and doesn't contain isoboot parameter description)

Comment: https://github.com/haraldh/dracut/issues/41

Answer (score 1):

This ought to be a question for dracut. It's only peripherally related to grub2 in that you have to pass the right kernel commands to boot proper. Here is a link to the index of shell scripts from the dracut project site containing the ones that set up iso-scan, hopefully this helps - it certainly helps me understand what's going on!
https://code.openhub.net/project?pid=5vezaKwZGfs&did=modules.d%2F90dmsquash-live&cid=d8dJ4k7PylM

Comment: Unfortunately https://code.openhub.net/ "Open Hub Code Search" launched 2012 was discontinued in 2016. c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Hub#Code_search